# How to read a Lable of another Access with VBA without opening the access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using two different `Access` applications to perform some tasks. On both of them, I 've stored a `Lable` with a text of the current `Version` of the application-Access. For example:

```
Access_1.Forms("2").Lable_1 = "Version 1.010"

Access_2.Forms("2").Lable_2 = "Version 1.029"
```

Each version of `Access_1` is compatible with a specific version of `Access_2`, thus I need to inform the user whether his set of `Access` is compatible with each other or not. So I am trying to find a way to perform a control check whenever the user opens `Access_1` like:

```
If Access_2.Forms("2").Lable_2.Value<>"Version 1.029" then
   msgbox "Your application is not compatible with Access2"
End if
```

Answer (score 1):

A label has no *Value* property, only the *Caption*:

```
If Access_2.Forms("2").Lable_2.Caption <> "Version 1.029" Then
    MsgBox "Your application is not compatible with Access2"
End if
```

Comment: Then your "Lable" isn't a _label_ control but a _textbox_ control.